# How to get only Intersected polygon in Open Layers 3

Tags: openlayers, intersection, splitting

I am trying to draw a line on polygon which I want to split,
**Example:**
I want to split 616 polygon as show in image

[image]

with below code when I tied to get intersected polygon I am getting 616,617,615 and Roads adjacent to 616.But I want only 616 which cut by line

```
draw.on('drawend', function (evt) {
                    var plcd = [], featureGeom;
                    var justNowFeature = evt.feature;
                    var line = evt.feature.getGeometry();
                     featureGeom = justNowFeature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();

                    console.log("FEATURESGEOJSON  " + featureGeom);
                    var features = plotboundary_layer.getSource().getFeatures();
                    for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
                        if (line.intersectsExtent(features[i].getGeometry().getExtent())) {
                            plcd.push(features[i].values_.plcd);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your approach. First problem is that you are checking line intersection with extent of the feature, which is smalest rectangle encompassing the whole feature. That's why you are getting roads also.

The second problem is that line crosses also neigboring features, that's why you are getting polygons 615 and 617. This would be solvable if `intersectsExtent` method would give number of points where line intersects polygon, but it return only true/false.

Library [Turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) can help here. Method `turf.lineIntersect` gives you geometry which is intersection of line and geometry. There is no extent involved here and from resulting geometry you can count interesecing points. If count is dividable by 2, line croses polygon.

Code would then look something like this:

```
var geoJSON = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var plcd = [];

draw.on('drawend', function (evt) {
  var intersectPoints, nPoints, featureGeoJSON, featureGeometry, lineGeoJSON, lineGeometry;
  lineGeoJSON = geoJSON.writeFeatureObject(evt.feature);
  lineGeometry = turf.getGeom(lineGeoJSON);
  var features = plotboundary_layer.getSource().getFeatures();
  for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
    featureGeoJSON = geoJSON.writeFeatureObject(features[i]);
    featureGeometry = turf.getGeom(featureGeoJSON);
    intersectPoints = turf.lineIntersect(featureGeometry, lineGeometry);
    nPoints = intersectPoints.features.length;
    if ((nPoints > 0) && ((nPoints % 2) == 0)) {
      plcd.push(features[i].values_.plcd);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I am getting Unknown Geometry Type error

Comment: My mistake, forgot that OpenLayers geometry is not the same as GeoJSON geometry (which is needed by Turf.js). Answer corrected.

Comment: great work.thank you